# How to create a simple nested signup form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm really stuck. Is there anyone who could help? What am I doing wrong? How can I create a simple nested form?

I have two models each with their own resources: Organizations and Members. An organization has multiple members and a member is only a member to one organization.

How can I create a simple nested form that signs up a new organization as well as one member for that organization?

My current attempt is below. The new view loads fine but then on submitting the form I get the error message **`unknown attribute 'org_name' for Member`**.

Although one way to go might be a form object and Activemodel, I would before implementing such first like it to work without such.

*Organization model:*

```
has_many :members, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :members, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
```

*Member model:*

```
belongs_to :organization
```

*Organizations controller:*

```
def new
  @organization = Organization.new
  @member = @organization.members.build
end

def create
  @organization = Organization.new(organizationnew_params)
  @member = @organization.members.build(organizationnew_params)
  if @organization.save && @member.save
    @member.send_activation_email     # Will Rails be able to get to this method? The method exists in multiple models and Rails should here use the version from the Member model.
    flash[:success] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
    redirect_to root_url
  else                          
    render 'new'
  end
end

def organizationnew_params
  params.require(:organization).permit(:org_name,
                                      :phone,
                   member_attributes: [:email,
                                      :username,
                                      :admin,
                                      :password,
                                      :password_confirmation
                                      ])
end
```

*Organizations new view:*

```
<%= form_for(@organization) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :org_name, %>
  <%= f.text_field :phone %>

  <%= f.fields_for :member do |p| %>
    <%= p.text_field :username %>
    <%= p.email_field :email %>
    <%= p.password_field :password %>
    <%= p.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :admin, true %> 
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "formbutton btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn the concept of form objects. You can easily implement this in Rails using ActiveModel.

```
class SignupForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  # define your signup form attributes
  attr_accessor :organization_name, :organization_note, :user_name, :user_fullname, :user_email

  def save
    organization = Organization.create(
      organization_name: organization_name, note: organization_note
    )

    user = organisation.users.create(email: user_email, name: user_name,
      full_name: user_fullname)

    return true
  end
end
```

This is not exactly correct implementation, but you can work from here. You can use this object as normal model in your forms:

```
<%= form_for(@signup_form) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :organization_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :user_name %>
  <%= f.text_Field :user_email %>
<% end %>
```

And in controller:

```
class SignupsController
  def new
    @signup_form = SignupForm.new
  end

  def create
    @signup_form = SignupForm.new(params[:signup_form])

    if @signup_form.save
      # success
    else
      # display errors
    end
  end
end
```

Of course you must also implement some validation inside SignupForm and handle case when validation fails.

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to follow your steps without yet the refactoring into a seperate form object yet. I've added this as an update to my original post. If I'm not mistaken my use of strong_params is similar the attr_accessor you use (I haven't used attr_accessor yet anywhere in my app so for consistency choose to use strong_params instead). In fact, if I do add `attr_accessible :members_attributes` to the organization model, it produces the error `undefined method 'attr_accessible' `.

Comment: I won't work like you wrote. You have has_many association so you cannot use methods for single resource.

Comment: I've changed that to `@member = @organization.members.build`

Comment: I would love to use the concept of form objects but would first like to have it working without form object. For example, I found RailsCast 416 on form objects (http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects) but there also the point of departure is a working system where there is a nested form without using form objects. The problem I have above would still be there also if I used form objects, right?

Answer (score 0):

One clean way to get to "intended situation" from "current situation" is by using promises. Make a single operation that chains your (promisified) write operations. Create the new org first. If no errors, create the user. Same for assigning the new user as an admin to the newly created organization.

https://github.com/lgierth/promise.rb

Thinking ahead though, I'll note that this only partially solves one of your original issues: new members making mistakes joining an existing organization. The promise can catch a user trying to create an existing organization, and you can build in some logic to add them as a new member...

One solution to this would be to have a form for a specific organization, with a new user hitting the form from a link for that organization, or inputting their organization and getting back a close match of organizations they may be meaning (there are APIs to help do this).

I hope that gives you some ideas.

If you're fine with one big form, just combine the views. The new view you mention in your last sentence will be needed anyway, so you're creating at least one new view.